# How to debug serverless deploy - hangs during packaging

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, puppeteer

While executing `sls deploy -s MY_STAGE -v`, serverless stops during packaging:

```
...
Serverless: Invoke deploy
Serverless: Invoke package
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:validate
Serverless: Invoke aws:common:cleanupTempDir
Serverless: Packaging service...
```

I use verbose and I set `SLS_DEBUG=*` to get more information. However, this doesn't show what's happening with packaging and why it is waiting/hanging...

What else can I do to check what's causing packaging to hang?

**More details:**

The package that is actually causing issues is `puppeteer`. If I comment out in the code:

```
// const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

That helps and `sls deploy` works. However, I want to use `puppeteer`.

Moreover, I also set `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1` - this hasn't made any difference.

In `.serverless` folder I can see services being zipped fine except the one that is using `puppeteer`.

If I do `sls package -s MY_STAGE` it hangs in the same place.

My environment:

```
Your Environment Information -----------------------------
   OS:                     win32
   Node Version:           8.9.4
   Serverless Version:     1.26.1
```

Comment: same issue.......

Comment: same issue .......

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-node-puppeteer